# Application to Stress Test in a Windows .NET Application

Tags: .net, stress-testing

I am developing a Windows .NET application (WinForms) and I need to simulate a stress test of the database and the application ( more than 100 conections).

**What tools do you recommend?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools like [AutomatedQA TestComplete](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/) allow you to make a script which simulates a user controlling your application. Running multiple scripts at the same time could be your stress test.

Comment: Using a functional test automation tool for performance testing is a very bad practice.

Comment: @John Care to elaborate? Is because of the performance overhead?

Comment: Using a functional test automation tool for stress testing is a bad practice, there are performance testing tools for that. And the number of concurrent users you can simulate is very limited, because with one instance you can only simulate one user. In general, for a stress test you need tens, hundreds, maybe even thousands of users, depending on the requirements.

Comment: And how do they differ? Do not both run script to 'drive' the application? And running more scripts at the same time simulates more users? I understand that tools written specifically for stress tests is suited better. Do you have any suggestions for such tools stress testing WinForm applications?

Comment: With a functional test automation tool you can only run one script/one user on a single workstation. A performance test tool runs the process without interface, so you can run many scripts/users on one workstation. The CPU and/or RAM are the limits of how many you can run simulateously. Also a performance test tool has extensive measurement capabilities, so you can measure response times, hits per second, etc. HP LoadRunner is such a tool.